# 100% errors from memtest86 after series of power surges; more likely to be motherboard or RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, power

The power grid where I live is unreliable, and we frequently have interruptions (and presumably surges). I usually have a UPS protecting my desktop computer, but my prior UPS developed a fault and I stupidly ran my computer for 2-3 weeks on only a belkin power strip (which claims surge protection, but tbd).

In any case, the computer started developing strange issues that initially manifested as USB devices not being found. I tested the USB hubs and devices on another computer and found no problems.

I decided to reinstall the OS, just in case something had shaken loose in the drivers. UEFI was unable to find the boot partition, and I couldn't boot.

On a whim I ran memtest86, and sure enough I found 100% errors. I tested each of my four DIMMs individually, and in different memory slots, and in each case am getting a 100% error rate.

So, is it more likely:
a) That the motherboard is fried in some way
b) That the DIMMs are bad

Buying hardware isn't exactly fast here. Also, my CPU is an i7, and there's a diminishing number of motherboards around that'll fit it (I believe) so motherboard swap may imply a new CPU, which'll be spendy.

Comment: It can be both and only trial and error can determine where the fault is.

Comment: just a suggestion, a power line conditioner might be more useful to you than a ups, though in your situation I would use both.  I run mine after the ups.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that all parts are seated correctly. One RAM stick slightly askew in a socket can mess up memtest.

Second,  have you made a bootable USB device, using [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or one of [the many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/ultimate-boot-cd/)? Boot from USB and run the memory test from that, eliminating the HDD and/or OS as the issue. For example, on Ubuntu, [run memtest86+](https://www.psychz.net/client/kb/en/how-to-check-ram-for-error-using-ubuntu-live-cd.html).

Also, if you can borrow a similar PC to test the RAM, check the sticks there: It seems unlikely all would be completely bad. If they're OK, then some hardware on the motherboard, *or the power supply*, is the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was running memtest from the USB key. I will do the other checks you suggest - thanks.